# Material UI TextField input type="date" doesn´t get event.target.value

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I´m using material ui and react grid from dev extreme to create a table with a input of type date, but when I try to type the date it doesn't recognize the value change until I get to the year value, which cleans the other values. Any Idea of what could be happening?

My Code:

```js
const DateEditor = ({ value, onValueChange }) => {
  return (
    <TextField
      value={value}
      type="date"
      onChange={event => {
        onValueChange(event.target.value)
        console.log(event.target.value)
      }}
    />
  );
};


const DateTypeProvider = React.memo(props => (
    <DataTypeProvider
      formatterComponent={DateFormatter}
      editorComponent={DateEditor}
      {...props}
    />
  ));
```

[image]

Nothing showing.

[image]

Showing when getting to year.

[image]

Deleting everything when I type next value.

Obs: It works perfectly when I select by the calendar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
just remove value props from the TextField
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `event.originalTarget` Instead of `event.target` Because `originalTarget`  refers to the element the event is attached to.

`target` Can change for example for a click event: `target` Is the inner element that was clicked but not the base element

Comment: Unfortunately, both originalTarget.value and just originalTarget come as undefined.